# How to set a fixed datetime.now() variable in Django using datetime.datetime

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I want to have two record dates of a blog post, one is the date the post was created on, and the last time/date the post was updated. But the issues is the date_created variable reset every time I make any changes.

```
...
from datetime import datetime

class Post(models.Model):
   ...
   date_created = datetime.now() # how to not reset this variable everytime when I update changes to the post?
   last_edited_date = datetime.now()
```

Comment: I would expect Fields instead of datetimes in your model.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DateField for this implementation. Please check this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) for more info.

> DateField.auto_now
>
> Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved.
> Useful for “last-modified” timestamps. Note that the current date is
> always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override.
>
> DateField.auto_now_add
>
> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created.
> Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is
> always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Django `models` fields. I suggest reading documentation as @Shivendra mentioned, but for a fast solution use these:

```
create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```